# Where are the melody roads located in Gunma prefecture?

Tags: japan, driving

I've heard many times that in Gunma prefecture, roads that play music when you drive over them can be found.

However, I've not been able to find a clear location for these roads. Supposedly, there is one located near Mount Haruna's lake and one near Kusatsu Onsen.

Is there an official map to find them or at least confirmed accounts?

EDIT: I actually found one by accident. Route 292 between Kusatsu and Haneo station.

Comment: http://www.gunmajet.net/travel/melody-roads-by-jessie-zanutig/

Comment: @mkennedy Im aware of that site, sadly its very vague.

Comment: Here's what the roads sound linke: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF9DYjkHXAE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This site](http://www.kirara.ne.jp/melody-line/) has an embedded map showing the road locations in Gunma Prefecture.  It is only in Japanese, but should be enough for you to find what you're looking for.

[image: Screenshot of embedded map]

Comment: Look for the music notes is the key I guess.

Comment: I don't think the notes appear on the standard Google map.  They seem to be added as labels to the dropped pins.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. Also, I am pretty sure Gunma Prefecture maintains a list of these roads on their website too, but I don't have time to look it up again now. There may be some more if you have the time. Otherwise this is pretty encompassing.

Comment: The official Gunma HP just links to the page in my answer:  http://www.pref.gunma.jp/07/h2800005.html

Comment: In that case there isn't any more. Upvoted for completeness.